# How to Remove "\n\r\n " in BeautifulSoup In Output

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code like This

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

page = open('doc1.html','rb').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())

# eng = soup.find_all(string = re.compile("righteou"))
# print(eng)

# heb = soup.findAll('p',{'dir':'RTL'})
# print(heb)
list=[]
all_tr =soup.findAll('tr')
for td in all_tr:
    all_td = soup.findAll('td')
    d={
    'hob':all_td[0].text.strip(),
    'english':all_td[1].text.strip()

        }
    list.append(d)
print(list)
```

My Output is like This

```
[{'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n      
              the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,', 'english': '\n\r\n                    We need to understand\r\n                    \r\n                        the idea that the Torah was given specifically on Mount\r\n                        Sinai,\r\n                    '}, {'hob': 'עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּ...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

iI Wannt To Remove \n\t  From Output Suh That my File Will Be cleaarr ..How Can I do This???????

Comment: Can you output of `all_td` or how `all_td[1]` looks like?

Comment: This looks like                                                                                                                  <tr>
            <td width="367" valign="top">
                <p dir="RTL">
                    עִנְיָן שֶׁנִּיתְּנָה הַתּוֹרָה עַל הַר סִינַי דַּוְקָא,
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="367" valign="top">
                <p>
                  
                       ........lots code here
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

Answer (score 1):

Split the words and join them with a space.

```
'english':" ".join(all_td[1].text.split())
```

This removes all "\n" , "\r", " ".