# bs4 - How to remove a lot of space (\n) when strip function doesn't work?

Tags: beautifulsoup

So I am playing around with bs4 where I was able to print out something what I wanted. Basically when I print the **item.text** I get a result of:

```
        40





        41





        42





        43





        44





        45
```

Usually what you do is that you write etc.

```
hello = item.text.strip()
print(hello)
```

but what it does is that it just does the first number correctly but the rest of the numbers it just the same space as the code above.

```
for item in bs4.findAll('div', {'class': 'size__dropdown'}):
  if item.find('div', {'class': 'picker-size__item '}):
     print(item.text.strip())
```

How can I make it so it prints out all in order or just more beautiful than all these spaces?

Comment: `" ".join(item.text.split())` Try this

Comment: you have to use `item.get_text(strip=True)`

Comment: @UpasanaMittal, your method work fined and is working as I wanted to! I haven't tried utks009 method yet but I can approve that your method work

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967574/how-to-remove-n-r-n-in-beautifulsoup-in-output/51968707#51968707

Comment: Solution by @UpasanaMittal was the answer :)

Comment: I have added this as answer in case you would like to accept. @CDNthe2nd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by

```
" ".join(item.text.split())
```